# Unable to @Mention someone in other Forest/Domain unless I am following the person

Tags: social, newsfeed

Please note that this question refers to the `@mention` functionality within a newsfeed (any newsfeed) ***only***. This does not in any way refer to the `ClientPeoplePicker` control in general. **The client people picker control works mostly as expected.**

Our SharePoint 2013 farm is deployed within the context of a resource Forest/Domain. Most of the users are in domains of the `ParentCompany.net` AD forest.

[image]

I have setup and properly configured the UPS and MySites. I am able to view and edit user profiles. Synchronization is occurring as expected.

**Issue**

- When I try to create an @Mention for a user that I am not following and who is in the `AM.ParentCompany.net` domain I do not see that user's name in my list and if I type `@[John Smith]` the mention does not work and is just added as text.
- Users whose accounts are in the resource Forest/Domain, do show up in the list. It does not matter if the user has deployed their MySite or not. The only way they show up in my list for @Mentions is if I follow them.

Here is an image of a colleague with a fully configured MySite and fully synced profile attempting to @mention my account in the `AM.ParentCompany.net` domain/forest and failing.

[image]

Here I am attempting to mention a colleague in the `AM.ParentCompany.net` domain/forest with the same results. None of the users in the `Everyone` list of this image has a configured MySite.

This situation persists across all news feeds, even on community sites with users added to the site collection. If I stop following someone, I lose the ability to @mention them.

[image]

**Regarding the ClientPeoplePicker in SPListItems *not* the Newsfeed**

Let's imagine that the user `Mark Z....` in this test case is Mark Zoidberg. Please note, the individual used as an example is in the member's group for the site.
[image]

1. If I create a task for user `Mark Zoidberg`, the first time I do it Mark's account does not appear in my typeahead dropdown. If I type `am\mzoidberg;` and press enter, the picker resolves the name.
2. Once I have typed a user's account name and it resolves, the user's full name appears in **my** type ahead and ***only*** my type ahead.
3. If another user accesses the same site and attempts to add a new item to the same list and assign it to Mark Zoidberg that user **does not** see his name in the type ahead until he also types `am\mzoidberg` repeating my steps from above.

Comment: could this be caused by app pool account in farm A not having permissions on databases used by farm B?

Comment: This is one farm only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ali was on the right track in blaming the people picker. I stumbled across this code today completely by accident but it has corrected my problem. The network where these systems reside has chronic issues with NetBIOS and WINS so this did not surprise me at all.

*[Users in any domain in the trusted forest receive a "No exact match was found" People Picker error message](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2874332)*

> **Cause**
>
> This issue occurs because, when you click OK, People Picker makes a
>   NetBIOS call to try to resolve the domain name. Because the customer
>   does not have WINS set up, a NetBIOS broadcast occurs. However, the
>   broadcast cannot find the trusted domains because broadcasts are not
>   enabled outside the subnet.

```
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ea silentlycontinue
# Enable the global setting for the farm. You must do this part only once.
$farm = get-spfarm
$farm.Properties
$farm.Properties["disable-netbios-dc-resolve"] = $true
$farm.Properties
$farm.Update()

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Set the SearchActiveDirectoryDomains property for a single web application. You should only do this part once per-web application.
# Note: SearchActiveDirectoryDomains is the PowerShell equivelent of peoplepicker-searchadforests
$wa = Get-SPWebApplication http://
# Save current PP settings to text file in case you need to refer to those
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains | out-file pp_settings_before.txt
# Clear the PP settings.
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Clear()

# You must repeat the following example for all the domains for which you want People Picker to work on this particular web application.
# The following is an example of adding three domains from the same forest and one domain from a trusted forest:
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$newdomain = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$newdomain.DomainName ='oneDomain.corp.contoso.com';  # specify the DNS name
$newdomain.ShortDomainName ='oneDomain'; # Specify the netbios name.
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($newdomain)

$newdomain2 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$newdomain2.DomainName ='corp.contoso.com';  # specify the DNS name
$newdomain2.ShortDomainName ='CORP'; # Specify the netbios name.
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($newdomain2)

$newdomain3 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$newdomain3.DomainName ='contoso.com';  # specify the DNS name
$newdomain3.ShortDomainName ='CTSO'; # Specify the netbios name.
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($newdomain3)

$newdomain4 = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPeoplePickerSearchActiveDirectoryDomain
$newdomain4.DomainName ='fabrikam.com';  # specify the DNS name
$newdomain4.ShortDomainName ='FAB'; # Specify the netbios name.
$wa.PeoplePickerSettings.SearchActiveDirectoryDomains.Add($newdomain4)
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Once you have added all the required domains, save settings for the web app.
$wa.update()
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly @mentions, these are people your following to use this feature.... if your not following or have none and carry on typing than it would go onto show everyone in forrest/domain that is configured to that web application!

if you cant see users within the everyone than there is an issue with your forrest/domain not included within the webapplicaiton..

the real questions to this is... is the AM.ParentCompany.net forrest/domain within the users account list??

by that i mean if you were to goto settings -> site settings -> people and groups 
...

click on new to test to see if the users from that forest exist? if not that you need to add that forrects including other forrest as well using stsadm:

stsadm tool to add multiple forrests syntax

```
STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:forrestName ,domain account,domain account password; forest:forrestName, domain account,domain account password;" -url yourwebapplicationurl
```

example

```
STSADM.exe -o setproperty -pn peoplepicker-searchadforests -pv "forest:AM.ParentCompany.net,accountname,accountpassword; forest:PM.jointventure.net,domain\accountname,accountpassword" -url http://yoursite-webapplication:13213/
```

**EDIT**

Yes your right a two way trust doesnt require the above code to be run! as you noted its only on the blogging/feeds features....

saying this... it looks like your @mentions / sharepoint site is screwed up.

> To access any microblog feature or the feeds, the user must have a
>   user profile and a My Site in SharePoint Server 2013. Anonymous
>   posting is not supported in any microblog feature in SharePoint Server
>   2013.

surely the accounts that are poping up without mysite shouldnt be?

Iv just tested on mysite setup using sharepoint 2013 in central admin. Made sure:

sheach scope for finding people = people

search scope for finding documents = all sites

site naming format is based on username (do not resolve conflicts)

read permission level is =  All Users (windows) ; Everyone ;

Security Trimming Options = Show all links regardless of permission

on newsfeed - Enable activities in My Site newsfeeds = true

privacy settings - Make My Sites Public = true

click ok..

then go onto make sure you have a personal site setup... this is important for @mentions as its part of (microfeeds / micro blogging features)

.. the above works for me and i can see accross all domains and follow any user

http://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2012/07/25/visual-guide-setting-up-my-sites-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Ali, thanks for the answer but there are a couple of issues with it. `1.` As per the MS documentation, the command you give is for configuration when the forest trust is uni-directional. As per my image above there is a bidirectional transitive trust in place. `2.` The people picker works fine. I can add anyone from any domain in any forest to the `Assigned To` field of task, for example. This is **ONLY** with @mentions in the news feed.

Comment: I did add people from `am.parentcompany.net` to the `My Site Visitors` group directly and this did not change anything. I think that we are being mislead by the documentation. I've read most of the documentation regarding the command you posted many times for SP 2007 and 2010 and despite the fact that the documentation for 2013 references it, I think it's not applicable based on witnessed behavior for @mentions.

Comment: What I stated earlier was false. I had a typo in the command. The `stsadm` command with the correct forest names changed nothing.

Comment: just ammended my answer!

Comment: I think you misunderstand what that quote says. **For the user to access the microsblog feature** this means a user must meet those requirements to **post** to the the newsfeed, not the mentioned in the newsfeed. My account does meet all of those requirements so I am able to use the microblog feature.

Comment: Just to be clear - your environment is MULTI-FOREST not just multiple domains, correct? This is an important distinction.

Comment: i have one forrest but within that forrest multiple domains. the trust tho was not bi directional but rather one way trust! looks like the issue is with a two way trust for some reason as its fine on my test site and on live!

Comment: Thanks for all your advice! I'll mock this up in Azure and let you know. But up to this point I am confident in my configuration. Search, people search, UPS sync, everything working. I think this is a bug.

Comment: its strange that it seems to occur on two way trust, saying that I did read somewhere that there is a bug in 2013 with two way trust in AD and @mentions.... but I don't know where... as soon as I find out ill post it here!

Comment: Just an FYI. We created cross-forest shortcut trusts and so far nothing has changed. We only just got them created so if I see anything new in 24 hours I will update.